# What is this SSD in my laptop

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, gparted, kubuntu

I have a laptop running Kubuntu. This laptop comes with a 32GB SSD inside. Is it a drive that I may store any old files on it? If possible, I would like to put my operating system onto it so I may boot faster. I tried to mount the partitions but it wouldn't let me. I would really like to make use of this drive if it is not being used. Any help is appreciated!

Specs:
HP Spectre XT TouchSmart Ultrabook 15-4013cl
OS: Kubuntu 14.04, 64-bit, Windows 8 has been removed
Processor: 4 X Intel Core i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz
Ram: 1.7 GiB

Image of GParted window: http://hichris.com/more/files/gparted.png

```
chris@TouchSmart:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdb print
Model: ATA SAMSUNG MZMPC032 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  8589MB  8588MB               Basic data partition
 2      8589MB  32.0GB  23.4GB  ext4
```

Comment: Just install the os on the 23.4GB partition.

Comment: I would like to know if that would be bad because I read that it is a cache for the hard drive. I also cannot mount the drive to access the files.

Comment: @ChristopherSmith, show us the command you're using to mount the files and what the error message is.

Comment: Looks like the 32G partition is formatted at least, please type `mount | grep /dev/sd` at the `$` prompt and add the output to your posting.

Comment: just a guess, but I'm thinking the SSD is there for IO caching, so it doesn’t hog ram.

Comment: @druciferre To mount, I am just right clicking on the partition in GParted and the Mount option is disabled.

Comment: @Hannu
chris@TouchSmart:~$ mount | grep /dev/sd
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/chris/2d31cceb-2f0d-4cf5-9c4d-95f10f19e5ce type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)

Comment: @FrankThomas does Linux know to use this? Or is that a Windows thing?

Comment: It is already mounted, open the files browser (drwaer-like icon, or type `nautilus &` in bash ) repeat press F9 to see the panel, and find `2d31cceb-2f0d-4cf5-9c4d-95f10f19e5ce` in it, click on it. The contents of your disk will be shown.

Comment: both systems do IO caching, but in differant ways, so I have no idea if your laptop was configured to use it. you should find some good info here on dm-cache: http://blog.kylemanna.com/linux/2013/06/30/ssd-caching-using-dmcache-tutorial/

Comment: `sudo e2label /dev/sdb2 TheDisk` - will set a more comprehensible name on it - next boot you will see that name in the left side panel of nautilus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment content:
The disk is already mounted as
2d31cceb-2f0d-4cf5-9c4d-95f10f19e5ce/ 
in /media/chris/

- open the files browser (drawer-like icon, or type nautilus & in bash ),
  repeat press F9 to see the panel,
  and find 2d31cceb-2f0d-4cf5-9c4d-95f10f19e5ce in it,
  click on it.

The contents of your disk will be shown.

`sudo e2label /dev/sdb2 TheDisk` - will set a more comprehensible name on it
 - next time you boot it will show with that name in the left side panel of nautilus.

---

To make it possible for a non-root user to use the disk space:

```
echo $USER
```

Will print your login name, say `theusername` (to be general)

with that knowledge type this in the shell

```
cd /media/chris/2d31cceb-2f0d-4cf5-9c4d-95f10f19e5ce/ 
sudo chown theusername:theusername .
echo >TEST.txt "This place is $USER's now"
cat TEST.txt
```

Note that last dot on the second line, that is the same as `this place` (current dir)

Comment: This partition is protected by root, is it safe to change this to me? Is this being used by anything else? Would it be possible to use this space as more RAM?

Comment: 1) check what there is on it - that will allow anyone to answer on your second question. Which then will lead to a good decision for your first question. 2) it will never be "RAM", just harddisk space.

Comment: The drive has 522.75 MiB used and an empty "lost + found" folder on it. Where is the rest of the used space coming from?

Comment: The used space is must be system overhead, compare to a 'drawer unit' you need drawers, these requires space in the unit. - I'll add a couple things above to make this complete.

Comment: I know what you mean but I wouldn't expect half a GB is used for the filesystem.

Comment: It grows with disk size, and actually requires quite a bit, even more so with complex filesystems - ext4 is one of those as it is 'journaling'.